# Python makes wrong comparison of two booleans

Tags: python, boolean, compare

I have this line of code:

```
print(isIndent(idxA), idxA[0]<idxB[0], isIndent(idxA) == idxA[0]< idxB[0])
```

In the code, I just test if the first statement has the same value as the second.

`isIndent` is a predicate and `idxA` and `idxB` are both tuples, but I run it I have this:
`True True False`

So the two members are both True, but the equality is False

So as you might expect, I just want a way to compare reliably the two expressions in a single row (without creating any temp value storage....)

Comment: You're not so dumb. In most other languages, the operator precedence allows your code to work as you intended.

Comment: A Minimum Reproducible Example would be `x=True; a=2; b=3; print(x==a<b); print(x==(a<b))`

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at this part:

```py
isIndent(idxA) == idxA[0]<idxB[0]
```

It says:
`if (isIndent(idxA) == idxA[0]) < idxB[0]`

it uses comparison chaining (thanks [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)) Which means it becomes:

`if (isIndent(idxA) < idxB[0]) and (idxA[0] < idxB[0])`

Because of the order it was written in!

In order to change that behaviour, use parenthesis

```py
print(isIndent(idxA), idxA[0]<idxB[0], isIndent(idxA) == (idxA[0]<idxB[0]))
```

Comment: Doesn't it do comparison chaining, so it's actually equivalent to `(isIndent(idxA) == idxA[0]) and (idxA[0] < idxB[0])`?

Comment: The solution is the same either way.

Comment: @Barmar I would think so as `if 0<x<1:` works in a natural manner as a range test. Knowing that, means that rearranging to `idxA[0]<idxB[0] == isIndent(idxA)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @Joffan I meant the solution of adding parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but if you regard it as just a precedence issue then you might guess that putting the inequality first would fix it without parantheses.

Comment: @Joffan That's true, but it's not a precedence issue, because they're all the same level of precedence in Python, and it's not left-associative because of chaining. That was the point of my comment.

Comment: @Barmar - Ehhh, it kind-of is left associative, because the first failed test working left to right will avoid subsequent tests.

Comment: @Joffan That's short-circuiting of logical operators, once you translate it to all the conditions separated by `and`.